# Hibernate join two classes via a common class field

Tags: java, hibernate

Let's say I have Hibernate entity class A, B, C. B is a field of both A and C. Now, I want to retrieve A based on a condition of C's other fields. How can I do that?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class A {
    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_ID")
    private B b;    

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "C")
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class C {
    ...

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=B)
    @JoinColumn(name="b_ID")
    private B b;   

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class B {
    ...
}
```

Now I want to get a list of A, that when C's records satisfy some condition. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
SELECT a FROM A a JOIN a.b b WHERE b.c.att = :value
```

There's even more alternatives.
I tried to show you that you can use `JOIN`s or use the full path for any attribute. For example:

```
SELECT a FROM A a WHERE a.b.c.att = :value
SELECT a FROM A a JOIN a.b b JOIN b.c c WHERE c.att = :value
```

But for those methods, you *must* have bidirectional relationship.
For this, update your B class:

```
public class B {
    @OneToMany( ... )
    private List<C> cList;
}
```

Without this, you can achieve the same result with:

```
SELECT a FROM A a WHERE a.b in ( SELECT c.b FROM C c WHERE c.att = :value )
```

Comment: I cannot do what u wrote above cause my case is not b.c, it s a.b and c.b, not b.c.

Comment: If you create a `private List<C> cList;` in your `B` class, then you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a NATIVE SQL QUERY to achieve this :

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select * from A a INNER JOIN B b ON 
a.b_ID = b.b_ID INNER JOIN C c ON b.b_ID = c.b_ID WHERE c.column = 123");

query.addEntity(A.class);

List<A> aList = query.list();
```

In the above mentioned SQL query you can add the Table "C" fields based on which you want to filter in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Is it equal to some query like `SELECT A.* FROM A join B join C where C.X=? GROUP BY A.id, A...`(complete that join 'ON' syntax) that you want to find?

If yes then this is just standard HQL or Criteria query in hibernate only if you have B to C relationship in your table B code something like :

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tableB")
public List<TableC> getTableCs;
```

if you did not want to add that bidirectional relationship then just use the native SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You want to fetch list of A when C satisfy some condition. we can also get this by mapping in C entity using @OneToMany :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "C")
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class C {
    ...

   @OneToMany( ... )
   private List<A> aList;
}
```